# Using Python function for cost calculation in GIS

Tags: python, gdal, function

I want to calculate the cost of two raster layers (ramdom, simulated) composed of values 1 and two, the first created randomly and the second by optimization using two associated cost layers. The code looks somewhat like below. However, I cannot make the function to read my second raster.

```
driver1 = gdal.GetDriverByName ('RST')
driver1.Register ()
ready = gdal.Open ('ramdom.rst', gdal.GDT_Byte)
cols = ready.RasterXSize
rows = ready.RasterYSize
bands = ready.RasterCount
geotransform = ready.GetGeoTransform()
read_ramdom = ready.ReadAsArray ()

global sum1, sum2, value1, value2
sum1, sum2, value1, value2 = 0, 0, 0, 0
classes = 2
global ssum
def cost(something):

          global ssum
          global sum1, sum2, value1, value2
          global classes
          while classes >=0:
             if something == something:
              something = ready.ReadAsArray()
             elif something == something2:
              something = simul_read.ReadAsArray()

              for i in range (0, rows):
                   for j in range (0, cols):
                      numb =  something [i, j]
                      if numb == 1:
                       one = names [numb -1]
                       ds1 = gdal.Open (one, gdal.GDT_Float32)
                       data1 = ds1.ReadAsArray (j, i, 1, 1)
                       value1 = data1 [0, 0]
                       sum1 = sum1+value1

                      if numb == 2:
                       two = names [numb -1]
                       ds2 = gdal.Open (two, gdal.GDT_Float32)
                       data2 = ds2.ReadAsArray (j, i, 1, 1)
                       value2 = data2 [0, 0]
                       sum2 = sum2+value2
                       classes = classes - 1

          ssum = sum1 + sum2 
          return ssum

simul_read = gdal.Open ('simulated.rst', gdal.GDT_Byte)
read_simulated = simul_read.ReadAsArray ()

A = cost(something) 
B = cost(something2)
C = cost(something) - cost(something2)

print ' The initial COST was :','   ', A, '\n'
print ' The final COST is :','   ', B, '\n'
print ' The gain is :', C , '\n'
```

Comment: It's better to provide the ***EXACT*** code than what it's "somewhat like", along with the exact error message or problem. The `import` statements are critical to making your code legible.

Comment: Print 'simul_read' variable and if it void then path to 'simulated.rst' raster is wrong (search by name, relative path, etc).

Comment: Hi again,if I comment out each of the input images, then the function works fine, but when I use it to run for the two raster layers, it only shows the result for the first one! Any comments? Thanks again.

Comment: Comments are reserved for requests for clarification,  not for content. As original poster (OP) your job is to [Edit] the Question to contain the relevant information needed to solve the question.